# Batch-Script defining Folderpath as Variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, path, definition

I am trying to write a little Batch-Script which imports a modified file into a specific Firefox Profile Folder.

The Problem is that every Firefox Profilefolder has a differently generated Name
(for example: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ab1c2def.default`)

Since I wanna make the Script work on multiple PC's , I can't hardcode the path, so I wanna be able to read the last part of the Path and use it as a variable so I can change my path to the desired folder to delete and add files in it.

Here is the code I begun with:

```
REM turning echo off
@echo off

REM changing directory to \Profiles Folder, behind it is the variable Folder.
cd %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

REM I wanna read the last Folder into a variable.
set userprofilefolder = Somehow read the folders behind \Profiles

REM now I wanna change my directory into that one folder.
cd %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%userprofilefolder%

REM Here I am deleting the old "prefs.js" file in the Folder.
del prefs.js

REM now I change my Folderpath to where my modified "prefs.js" file lays.
cd path\where\my\prefs.js\file\lies

REM now I copy my fresh prefs.js" file into my Folder.
copy "prefs.js" "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%userprofilefolder%"

REM Here I exit my .bat file.
exit
```

So how do I do that?

Comment: Why does your question title have Vbscript?

Comment: I was working with an vbs script before, I accidentally wrote that in instead of CMD/Batchfile. My Bad. How can I correct the question?

Comment: @O.Kaya, what do you think is the [edit] button for? ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl The "edit" Hyperlink is awesome! How did you do that?

Comment: I just wrote `[edit]` in the command, that's it; however, there is already such a link at the bottom of your question (`share  edit  close  flag`)...

Comment: Like this? [edit] Which command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REM Turn echo off.
@echo off

REM Change directory to Firefox folder, this is where the profiles.ini file exist.
cd /d "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox" || exit /b 1

REM Read profiles.ini and call :profiledir with the value of each path key found.
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (profiles.ini) do (
    if /i "%%~A" == "path" call :profiledir "%%~B"
)
exit /b

:profiledir

REM Set local environment. Any settings i.e cd will be temporary.
setlocal

REM Check if ".default" in path to continue.
echo "%~1"| find ".default" || exit /b 1

REM Change to the profile dir.
cd /d "%~1" || exit /b 1

REM Copy prefs.js to current dir.
echo copy /y "path\to\my\prefs.js" "prefs.js"
exit /b
```

The file named `profiles.ini` contains the paths to the profile folders.
The file is in ini format and you can find the path value of each path key.

You can have many profile folders so I use a `find ".default"`
to continue only if the folder contains that string.

Note:

- If paths are network paths then `pushd` and `popd` may need to be used
  instead of `cd`.

---

**Description of operation**

```
REM Change directory to Firefox folder, this is where the profiles.ini file exist.
cd /d "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox" || exit /b 1
```

This changes current directory. `||` is run command on right side
if left side command failed. If failed, will exit with errorlevel 1.

Note: Use `cd /?` and `exit /?` for syntax help.

```
REM Read profiles.ini and call :profiledir with the value of each path key found.
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (profiles.ini) do (
    if /i "%%~A" == "path" call :profiledir "%%~B"
)
```

This `for` loop reads the profiles.ini file. Delimiters set are `=` which
an ini file uses to delimit the key from the value. Token `1` will be the
key placed in `%%A` while the token `*` will be the value stored in `%%B`.
If the key equals the key named `path`, then call the label named
`:profiledir` with 1st argument of value of path which should be a path
to a profile folder.

Note: Use `for /?` and `call /?` for syntax help.

```
:profiledir
```

This is the called label. A call to a label can pass arguments which
makes it convenient for passing something like i.e. a path. Arguments
received are in the format of `%1`, `%2` ... `%9`. The tilde i.e. `%~1`
removes outer double quotes. Called labels return back to the caller
when finished.

```
REM Check if ".default" in path to continue.
echo "%~1"| find ".default" || exit /b 1
```

`"%~1"` is the 1st argument quoted. It is echoed to the `find` command and if
`.default` is found, then it will continue. The `|` is known as a pipe where
stdout from the `echo` is passed to the stdin of `find`.

Note: Use `find /?` for syntax help.

```
REM Change to the profile dir.
cd /d "%~1" || exit /b 1
```

Same as main code `cd` except it is set local so only lasts with in
the called label.

```
REM Copy prefs.js to current dir.
echo copy /y "path\to\my\prefs.js" "prefs.js"
```

The `/y` argument of `copy` allows overwrite without confirmation so the
`del` is obsolete.

Note: Use `copy /?` for syntax help.

Finally: Remove the `echo` in front of the `copy` command if satisfied that it shows the copy command is OK.

Comment: michael_heath thank you very much for the help, but now I got the problem that I don't know how to change the code to fit my needs. I don't know how to interpret the Syntax, Id need to be able to explain my Coworkers how it works. Is there any Guide that teaches the ABC of .batch Scripting? Thanks alot again

Comment: Added more details to the answer. The `for` loop gets the paths and the called label handles the `cd` of paths, copying etc. I am not sure of your needs so unsure how to help. ABC of batch scripting is many, use a search engine. This site has much to learn from.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ill read a vbs guide so I can follow up everything.

Comment: Why not simply use `for /R "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" /D %A in (*.default) do @echo:%A %~nxA` on cmdline